# (Intellij Idea PHP) mapping of local project folder files to local server project root directory

Tags: php, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij Idea as a editor for php WebApp project. I have a project files situated at `D:\projectRoot` and my `localhost` project files are at `C:\xampp\htdocs\projectRoot`.

I always work on the project files situated in D drive. Now what I would like to is that, when I run the project all project files of D drive should get copied to `C:\xampp\htdocs\projectRoot`, that means I wanted to deploy the project files from D drive to localhost server directory

Is this possible into Intellij Idea?

Comment: i believe you can do that using File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Deployment, then setup your mappings accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to configure Deployment to a Local or mounted folder. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-deployment-in-product.html